# Specifying only some template parameters at call time

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, icc, template-argument-deduction

Consider the short piece of variadic template code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int Dim, class... Idcs>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Idcs) == 1> doit(Idcs... idcs)
{}

int main()
{
    doit<0>(1);
}
```

When I compile this using GCC/Clang, this compiles fine and `Idcs` is deduced as `(int)`.

However, when I try to compile this using Intel's Compiler (version 18.0.0, 20170811), it for some reason thinks I'm manually specifying `Idcs` as an empty parameter pack, and then the `enable_if_t` fails.

The compiler error from icc:

```
myfile.cpp(9): error: no instance of function template "doit" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (int)
    doit<0>(1);
    ^
myfile.cpp(4): note: this candidate was rejected because there is a type mismatch after argument substitution
  std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Idcs) == 1> doit(Idcs... idcs)
                                         ^

compilation aborted for myfile.cpp (code 2)
```

This can be fixed by changing the call inside of `main()` to specify all template parameters fully

```
doit<0, int>(1);
```

However, I would like to understand why the original code doesn't give the same result on all C++ 14 compilers. Is this something which is expected to compile successfully/unsuccessfully, or is this somehow undefined behavior, and why?

For reference, these are the commands I'm using to compile (on Linux, various versions/flavors):

```
g++ -std=c++14 myfile.cpp
clang++ -std=c++14 myfile.cpp
icc -std=c++14 myfile.cpp
```

Comment: @bolev added, I also changed the first template parameter type to `int` since I accidentally had some other headers irrelevant headers being included which defined `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in icc that was fixed in v19: https://godbolt.org/z/k1vbY9

More investigation reveals that icc v18 (which does not compile your code) correctly deduces `Idcs` without `enable_if`: https://godbolt.org/z/WCZ_w8

```
template<size_t Dim, class... Idcs>
size_t doit(Idcs... idcs)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Idcs) == 1);
    return sizeof... (Idcs);
}

auto test()
{
    return doit<0>(1); // correctly returns 1 even on icc v18
}
```